# How can I remove a specific field on MongoDB using java?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

I want to hide id_jadwal in the display JSON. but now id_jadwal keep display on my JSON I want to hide id_jadwal in the display JSON. I am using MongoDB and java jx-rs for my framework and Jackson

```
[
    {
        "name": "Style",
        "startTimestamp": 1507611720,
        "endTimestamp": null,
        "place": "gh",
        "description": "gh",
        "status": "DONE",
        "creator": {
            "name": "Pulan",
            "email": "sd@gmail.com",
            "photo": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Q5Tx0bdvkAU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAEyU/83rb_x1tyXA/photo.jpg"
        },
        "invitedUsers": [
            {
                "name": "Petra",
                "email": "sd.class@gmail.com",
                "photo": "",
                "present": false,
                "nearby": false
            }
        ],
        "id_jadwal": null,
        "_id": "59db02e8212cba197b7e9d2c"
    }

}]
```

My Code:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("creator.email", email);
query.put("status", status.toString());
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    String jsonUser = cursor.next().toJson();

    Event event = objectMapper.readValue(jsonUser, Event.class);
    //objectMapper.setVisibility(event.getId_jadwal(), Visibility.NONE);

    events.add(event);
    events.remove("id_jadwal");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to explicitely exclude your field at request level, using [Projection](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/model/Projections.html) :

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).projection(Projections.exclude("id_jadwal").iterator();
```

Comment: keep display id_jadwal but become to null value

Comment: probably because your Event class has id_jadwal property, but your ObjectMapper can not get value from query result (as we removed it).